# move folders from folder list to other folder list using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

hello I want to move or copy many folders from some folder list to other folder list I use `glob` and `shutil` libraries for this work.

first I create a folder list :

```
import glob

#paths from source folder
sourcepath='C:/my/store/path/*'
paths = glob.glob(sourcepath)
my_file='10'
selected_path = filter(lambda x: my_file in x, paths)
#paths from destination folder
destpath='C:/my/store/path/*'
paths2 = glob.glob(destpath)
my_file1='20'
selected_path1 = filter(lambda x: my_file1 in x, paths2)
```

and now I have two lists from paths(selected_path,selected_path1)

now I want to movie or copy folder from first list(`selected_path`) to second list(`selected_path1`)

finaly I try this code to move folders but without success :

```
import shutil
for I,j in zip(selected_path,selected_path1)
     shutil.move(i, j)
```

but that cant work,any ide how to do my code to work ?

Comment: What are trying to achieve with your `lambda` functions? You can filter paths from `glob` function immediately.

Comment: @direprobs that is no problem the problem is here `shutil.move(i, j)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Obviously your use of `lambda` isn't useful, `glob` function can perform this filtering. This is what `glob` really does, so you're basically littering your code with more unnecessary function call, which is quite expensive in terms of performance.

Look at this example, identical to yours:

```
import glob

# Find all .py files
sourcepath= 'C:/my/store/path/*.py'
paths = glob.glob(sourcepath)

# Find files that end with 'codes'
destpath= 'C:/my/store/path/*codes'
paths2 = glob.glob(destpath)
```

Second, the second `glob` function call may or may *not* return a list of directories to move your directories/files to. This makes your code dependent on what C:/my/store/path`contains. That is, you must guarantee that 'C:/my/store/path` must contain only directories and never files, so `glob` will return only directories to be used in `shutil.move`. If the user later added files not folders to C:/my/store/path that happened to end with the name 'codes' and they didn't specify any extensions (e.g, codes.txt, codes.py...) then you'll find this file in the returned list of `glob` in `paths2`. Of course, guaranteeing a directory to contain only subdirectories is problematic and not a good idea, not at all. You can test for directories through `os.path.isdir`

Notice something, you're using `lambda` with the help of `filter` to filter out any string that doesn't contain `10` in your first call to `filter`, something you can achieve with `glob` itself:

```
glob.glob('C:/my/store/path/*10*')
```

Now any file or subdirectory of C:/my/store/path that contains 10 in its name will be collected in the returned list of the `glob` function.

Third, `zip` truncates to the shortest iterable in its argument list. In other words, if you would like to move *every* path in `paths` to *every* path in `paths2`,  you need `len(paths) == len(paths2)` so each file or directory in `paths` has a `directory` to be moved to in `paths2`.

Fourth, You missed the semicolon for the `for` loop and in the call for `shutil.move` you used `i` instead of `I`. Python is a case-sensitive language, and `I` uppercase isn't exactly the same as `i` lowercase:

```
import shutil
for I,j in zip(selected_path,selected_path1)            # missing :
     shutil.move(i, j)                                  # i not I
```

Corrected code:

```
import shutil
for I,j in zip(selected_path,selected_path1)            # missing :
     shutil.move(I, j)                                  # i not I
```

Presumably, `paths2` contains only subdirectories of C:/my/store/path directory, this is a *better* approach to write your code, but definitely *not* the best:

```
import glob

#paths from source folder
sourcepath='C:/my/store/path/*10*'
paths = glob.glob(sourcepath)

#paths from destination folder
destpath='C:/my/store/path/*20*'
paths2 = glob.glob(destpath)

import shutil
for i,j in zip(paths,paths2):
     shutil.move(i, j)
```

*Still some of the previous issues that I mentioned above apply to this code.

And now that you finished the long marathon of reading this answer, what would you like to do to improve your code? I'll be glad to help if you still find something ambiguous.

Good luck :)

Comment: you are complete correct good job that work,but if i use `shutil.copy` and not `shutil.move` i take `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:` any idea why 
?

Comment: @jessie jes `shutil.move` actually raises the same exception if you try to move a file without the right privilege of your OS. You get `Permission denied` exception because you're trying to perform a task without the right privilege. Running cmd as administrator can be a solution.